# angular-cli.json - including scripts in webpack, + jquery in widget

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, jhipster

I have a jhipster-project. I am trying to integrate adminLTE in it. Have achieved most of the thing.

Here, when I see adminLTE project structure, angular-cli.json contains following entries

```
"styles": [
            "content/css/vendor.css",
            "content/css/global.css",
             "styles.css",
            "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
            "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
            "../node_modules/ionicons/css/ionicons.css",
            "_variables.less",
            "../node_modules/icheck/skins/flat/blue.css",
            "../node_modules/morris.js/morris.css",
            "../node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css",
            "../node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css",
            "../node_modules/bootstrap3-wysihtml5-bower/dist/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "../node_modules/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
        "../node_modules/raphael/raphael.js",
        "../node_modules/morris.js/morris.js",
        "../node_modules/jquery-sparkline/jquery.sparkline.js",
        "../node_modules/jquery-knob/dist/jquery.knob.min.js",
        "../node_modules/moment/moment.js",
        "../node_modules/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
        "../node_modules/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap3-wysihtml5-bower/dist/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.js",
        "../node_modules/icheck/icheck.js",
        "../node_modules/admin-lte/dist/js/app.js",
        "assets/js/scripts.js"]
```

in my webpack.dev.js, I am trying to find a way to include these scripts and css.

I see jquery is already there with

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: "jquery",
                jQuery: "jquery"
            }),
```

and I added morris.js by doing this

```
alias: {
                'morris.js': 'morris.js/morris.js'

            }
```

If I have to make use of these scripts file I have to manually include them in component.ts like this :

```
import  'morris.js';
import 'jquery-knob';
import 'bootstrap-datepicker';
import 'jqueryui';
import 'daterangepicker';
import 'jquery-slimscroll';
import 'admin-lte';
```

is there any way, that I can add them in webpack config. also, how should I add CSS used in angular-cli to my project.

I see in package.json that, yarn webpack:build , triggers config webpack/webpack.dev.js.. so thinking here is the file i have to do something, but not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

yeah.. you are right!! that worked. Thanks a lot!! I can see the scripts.js is getting loaded in browser and its hitting a breakpoint. 
I am getting another issue in script.js though. It contains following code.

jQuery.widget.bridge('uibutton', jQuery.ui.button);

//receive calls from typescript code to update the layouts

```
var AdminLTE = (function() {
  return {
    init: function() {
        jQuery(function(){
            jQuery.AdminLTE.layout.activate();
            jQuery.AdminLTE.layout.fix();
            jQuery.AdminLTE.layout.fixSidebar();
      });
    }
  }
})(AdminLTE||{});
```

and it says Cannot read property 'bridge' of undefined.
How should I address this. Widget is there in the Jquery.

Thanks.
Also, where I can read about build chain of jhipster.. information is only in bits and pieces..it takes lot of time debugging ..

Thanks Again!..
Regards